# Ensure abstract Python method is implemented as a class method (or not)

Tags: python, oop, abstract-class, abc

I have an abstract Python class (v3.8.10) with two abstract methods, `save()` and `load()`.

```py
import abc

class Parent(abc.ABC):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def load(*args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

The purpose of writing such a class is typically to establish an API for downstream development: if you want to inherit from this class, you have to implement `save()` and `load()`. Now the questions:

- Is there a way to guarantee that child classes of `Parent` must implement one of these methods (say `load()`) as a `@classmethod` in order to instantiate the class?
- Conversely, is there a way to *prevent* one of these methods (say `save()`) from being implemented as a `@classmethod?`

These would be additional API constraints required by class `Parent`. For example, the following class is instantiable, because it implements `save()` and `load()`:

```py
class GoodChild(Parent):

    def save(self, savefile):
        """Save instance-specific data to a file."""
        print(f"saving data to {savefile}")
        # ...

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, loadfile):
        """Load data from a file, creating an instance."""
        print(f"loading data from {loadfile}")
        # ...
        # return cls(data)
```

But is it possible to write `Parent.save()` and `Parent.load()` in such a way that the following classes are *not* instantiable?

```py
class BadChild(Parent):

    def save(self, savefile):
        print("This is fine.")

    def load(self, loadfile):
        print("Uh oh, this should be a class method!")


class NaughtyChild(Parent):

    @classmethod
    def save(cls, savefile):
        print("Uh oh, this shouldn't be a class method!")

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, loadfile):
        print("This is fine.")
```

```py
>>> papa = Parent()
TypeError: #Can't instantiate abstract class Parent with abstract methods load, save

# Can instantiate this class.
>>> child_1 = GoodChild()

# But can also instantiate these. Can we modify Parent so that these raise TypeError?
>>> child_2 = BadChild()
>>> child_3 = NaughtyChild()
```

Or, if you think such a requirement would be a really bad idea, why?

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. In Python, many things are possible, but some are very inconvenient.

Why would you want to prevent implementations to use `classmethod` ? You did not said what `load` should do, or of what type are its arguments. And it does not make much sense from the [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) point of view.

But if you really want, that's what [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) is for in Python : check that something conforms to the expected signature. Even so, having either one of the two methods `classmethod` but not the other is quite difficult to express, if not just impossible.
So let me ask you a question : is it really a problem that there are some `classmethod`s ? You can't know how the abstract methods will be implemented.
And are `staticmethod`s a problem too ?
If so, Python may not be the language to craft such rigid contracts.